# Find the opposite vector of a certain magnitude given a random vector that has the origin of the coordinate system as its initial point.

Tags: trigonometry, vector-spaces

Hi it's my first post here ever.

I was trying to write a simple program that simulates the orbit of the ISS under the Earth's gravitational influence.

The Earth will be the origin of the coordinate system. I wanted to simulate the gravitational acceleration that the ISS is under at any given moment by taking its coordinates and applies to it an acceleration vector that points to the Earth with a magnitude of 9.8. However I struggled to arrive at an elegant solution.

With my limited mathematical knowledge the best I could do now is to separate the problem into 4 cases, with the ISS' coordinate being in one of the 4 quadrants of the coordinate system, then apply some basic trigonometry to find the gravitational acceleration vector. While this solution certainly 'works', it is both clunky and not all-encompassing.

I would really appreciate it if someone could point me to the right direction.

tldr; Find the vector of a certain magnitude with the origin of the coordinate system as its initial point given a random coordinate that it passes through.

PS: Sorry for any grammatical or spelling mistake as English is not my first language. I had to look up mathematical terms in English so the idea I tried to convey couldn't be as clear and concise as I would have wanted it to be.